# Unit Testing methods within which extension methods are used for external resources

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, identityserver4, xunit.net

I need to Unit test `RequestToken` method that uses `HttpClient` and extension method `RequestPasswordTokenAsync`.

I have got a `null` reference exception even when a `delegatingHandler` is passed to the `HttpClient`.

```
var delegatingHandler = new DelegatingHandlerStub(false);
var httpClient = new HttpClient(delegatingHandler);

var tokenServices = new TokenServices(httpClient)
tokenServices.RequestToken(passwordTokenRequest);  //exception


 public class TokenServices : ITokenServices
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        public TokenServices(HttpClient httpClient) 
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;           
        }

            public async Task<TokenResponse> RequestToken(PasswordTokenRequest request)
        {           

            var response = await _httpClient.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(request);

            }

    }

     public class DelegatingHandlerStub : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private readonly Func<HttpRequestMessage, CancellationToken, Task<HttpResponseMessage>> _handlerFunc;
        public DelegatingHandlerStub(bool toThrowException)
        {
            _handlerFunc = (request, cancellationToken) =>
            {
                if (toThrowException)
                    throw new Exception();

                return Task.FromResult(request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK));
            };

        }

        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return _handlerFunc(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }


namespace IdentityModel.Client
{

    public static class HttpClientTokenRequestExtensions
    {
        public static Task<TokenResponse> RequestPasswordTokenAsync(this HttpMessageInvoker client, PasswordTokenRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you get around this issue by not using an extension method to access an external resource?

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I have to write a wrapper around HttpClient.

If there are a better solution, please post it here